# i am position my image along y-axis But on inluding (<!DOCTYPE html>) code does not work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, drag

Here is my code, part of the HTML and the javascript. I used BOOTSTRAP, JQUERY.UI.JS and JQUERY 1.11.01 libraries in my code.

```
<!-- HTML PART OF CODE -->

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
<-- BOOTSTRAP LIBRABY -->       
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<!-- BOOTSTRAP LIBRABY -->



</head>
<body>
<!-- MAIN BODY CODE -->
    <div class="ui-widget-content" style="padding:10px;">
<div class="picturecontainer" style="overflow: hidden; position: relative; width: 900px; height: 350px; border: 1px solid #888; margin:auto;">

<img style="position: absolute;" class="headerimage ui-corner-all img-responsive" src="http://shushi168.com/data/out/79/35971308-fish-picture.jpg" />

</div>
</div>
<!-- MAIN BODY CODE -->
<!-- HTML PART ENDS HERE-->
<!-- THIS IS JAVASCRIPT PART OF MY CODE-->

<script src="assets/js/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>
    var y1; 
    var y2;
    $(function(){
    $(".headerimage").css('cursor','-webkit-grab');
    y1 = $('.picturecontainer').height();
    console.log(y1);
     y2 = $('.headerimage').height();
    console.log(y2);
    $(".headerimage").draggable({
                         scroll: false,
                         axis: "y",
                         drag: function(event, ui) {
                         if(ui.position.top >= 0)
                            {
                               ui.position.top = 0;
                             }

                          else if(ui.position.top <= y1 - y2)
                             {
                                ui.position.top = y1 - y2;
                             }

                          else if(ui.position.bottom <= 0 )
                             {
                                ui.position.bottom = 0;
                             }

                           else if(ui.position.bottom <= y2 - y1)
                             {
                                ui.position.bottom = y2 - y1;
                             }
            },
            stop: function(event, ui) {
            //####
        }
        });                    
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

In above code, if i remove my `"<!DOCTYPE html> "` tag my code works. But i need `<!DOCTYPE html>` for my  html5. How can i do that?

Comment: can you describe `does not work` - as it stands, that's not at all helpful

Comment: make sure there is nothing above the `<!DOCTYPE html>` like in this example the comment and white rule.

Comment: `I HAVE USED BOOTSTRAP` - looks like you load bootstrap CSS - isn't bootstrap also a JS library?

Comment: if  I run my code without using html 5 "<!DOCTYPE html>"  declaration my code works fine. But if I  don't declare "<!DOCTYPE html>" draging of image doesn't work.

Comment: actually  i am facing confilct between html5 and jquery.ui.js

Comment: What do you expect from your code?you want to drag the image along the y-axis?

Comment: yes @GraveyardQueen i want to drag image along y-axis.

Comment: Proly somewhere in your code you may be using `$.parseHTML`

Comment: @Novice i didn't find any thing like  $.parseHTML in my code.

Comment: Every length value in CSS needs to have a unit specified (unless the value is zero.) Your code only sets unitless values. In Quirks Mode browsers usually fix your mistake by assuming you meant `px`, but the HTML5 doctype triggers standards mode. (FYI, using http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=javascript+css+doctype or similar you could have found several explanations of that issue yourself.)